# Javascript mulilevel array sort based on key, but with logical structure in first key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, directory, tree

I have some specyfic issue. I have a lot of records that looks like this:

```
let a = [
  [[1,2,3], ... , b],
  [[1,2,5], ... , a]
  [[1,2], ... , a],
  [[1], ... , z]
  [[1,2,5], ... , a],
  [[1,2,3,5], ... , b],
  [[1,2,3,4], ... , a],
  [[1,3], ... , a],
  [[1,3,3], ... , b],
  [[1,6], ... , a],
  [[1,3,5], ... , d],
  [[1,2,4], ... , b],
  [[1,3,1], ... , a],
  [[1,3,2], ... , c],
]
```

So I have array (level 0) with arrays (level 1) that contains some data and array (level 2) of path parts.

Now, I have to sort array level 0 by for example key 2, but the paths should still build logical tree or something like that.

So if I sort by, for example, last key, I shoud get something like this:

```
let b = [
  [[1], ... , z],
  [[1,2], ... , a],
  [[1,2,5], ... , a]
  [[1,2,3], ... , b],
  [[1,2,3,4], ... , a],
  [[1,2,3,5], ... , b],
  [[1,2,4], ... , b],
  [[1,2,6], ... , d],
  [[1,3], ... , a],
  [[1,3,1], ... , a],
  [[1,3,3], ... , b],
  [[1,3,2], ... , c],
  [[1,3,5], ... , d],
  [[1,6], ... , a],
]
```

SOLVED!

I found that the best and easiest solution comes with lodash library. So I could first sort by the first column, and then by selected key - so the structure becomes logical, and sorted are only "files inside folders".

Here is the code:

```
let a = [
  [[1,2,3], ... , b],
  [[1,2,5], ... , a]
  [[1,2], ... , a],
  [[1], ... , z]
  [[1,2,5], ... , a],
  [[1,2,3,5], ... , b],
  [[1,2,3,4], ... , a],
  [[1,3], ... , a],
  [[1,3,3], ... , b],
  [[1,6], ... , a],
  [[1,3,5], ... , d],
  [[1,2,4], ... , b],
  [[1,3,1], ... , a],
  [[1,3,2], ... , c],
]

function TreeStructure(arr, column, dir) {
  // Create array duplicate to avoid changes on base array
  let a = [...arr];
  // flip sort direction based on passed value
  // Magic of _Lodash - firstly, sort by the tree ignoring the last item of the tree path,
  // Then sort by the selected key
  a = _.sortBy(a, [
    function (item) {
  // first - sort by the first array, but with ignoring the last item
  // as I mentioned - it's representation of folder tree
  // so the last element is the file
      const value = item[0].length > 1 ? item[0].slice(0, item[0].length - 1).join("-") : item[0].length;
      return value;
    },
    function (item) {
  // Then, sort by the selected column
  // To prevent errors if some objects or arrays comes in the column I convert them to string
  // And to avoid specyfic JS sorting, I convert it to lowercase.
      const value = item[column].toString().toLowerCase();
      return dir === "asc" ? value : -value;
    },
  ]);

return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest approach is to use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with options and strings of the wanted arrays joined by a separator.

This method respects values with more than one digit and sorts naturally.

For sorting different columns, you could take functions for each sort methods and an object which has the key of the column and returns a function as callback for sorting.

```js
const
    sortPath = col => (a, b) => a[col].join('-').localeCompare(
        b[col].join('-'),
        undefined,
        { numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' }
    ),
    sortAlpha = col => ((a, b) => a[col].localeCompare(b[col])),
    cols = { path: sortPath(0), title: sortAlpha(1) },
    array = [[[1, 2, 3], 'b'], [[1, 2, 5], 'a'], [[1, 2], 'a'], [[1], 'z'], [[1, 2, 5], 'a'], [[1, 2, 3, 5], 'b'], [[1, 2, 3, 4], 'a'], [[1, 3], 'a'], [[1, 3, 3], 'b'], [[1, 6], 'a'], [[1, 3, 5], 'd'], [[1, 2, 4], 'b'], [[1, 3, 1], 'a'], [[1, 3, 2], 'c']];

array.sort(cols.path);
array.forEach(a => console.log(JSON.stringify(a)));

console.log('----------');

array.sort(cols.title);
array.forEach(a => console.log(JSON.stringify(a)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It's almost perfect, but I have to be able to choose by which key I'm sorting. For example, if I have values that represents: [[paths-array], 'title', 'size', 'status', 'content'], I need to option to sort the same way, but by second or third key.